Data factory error. How to troubleshoot bug in activity itself
A data flow activity seems to have a bug.  The activity type "HDInsightSpark" sends back an error that says: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
It claims that the failure type is "User configuration issue".
Even if I configured something wrong, that is not enough to deserve such a meaningless error.  The error is not actionable in any way, nor does it give me any way to investigate more deeply.
This was working yesterday and all of a sudden it fails today, despite the fact that I made no changes.  The activity is happening on an azure-managed-IR.
Is there any way to dig into the details for something like this?  Is there a back-end log?  Can I get a stack trace?  Can I get a memory dump?

Can you provide the error image for better understanding?
